# Running a Groovy script during release:prepare

Tags: maven, groovy, maven-release-plugin

I want to use a Groovy script (using `groovy-maven-plugin`) to tune the way the `maven-release-plugin` is invoked. I need to use a Groovy script since profile activation lacks the necessary expressive power to conditionally activate the configuration the way I want.

However, I do not understand how I can inject the necessary Groovy code to run *during* release:prepare before the subprocess starts. During normal `install` or `verify` goals, I can just bind the script to the `validate` or `initialize` phases, but I cannot get this to work with `release:prepare`.

To clarify, what I am trying to do is to have different `preparationGoals`, `completionGoals` etc depending on the results of a deeper inspection of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally checking out the source code to `maven-release-plugin` and going through the code, I conclude that the behavior is hard-coded into the plugin, with no possibility to customize.

Yet another reason not to use this plugin, I guess.